# How to validate two user's details on a single page, using jquery's validate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a page where first user's details are entered. 
Say,
*First user input fields are- Name[mandatory], Address[mandatory], Contact No.[mandatory] and Photo. [optional]*
There is a + button if it wants to enter another details. 
If + is clicked, the same details with different input names gets cloned.
*Second user details - sName[mandatory], sAddress[mandatory], sContact No.[mandatory] and sPhoto[optional].*

Now, using jquery's .validate how to validate second user?

Say, if the first user entered details, clicked + , entered sContact No. , it should display error as all s fields are missing. 
Similarly, if I validate sName by using 'depends' , what if sName is empty? All other fields will be entered without validation in that case.

Please suggest how to put validation in such case?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example, or add the code you are having trouble with to your question. It makes helping a lot easier.

Comment: Jquery validate will not work for this. All you need to do is on a plus button insert the data into the array and use array methods(some. find) for checking the existence of an item in the array.